# using pdf2text class inside a loop

Tags: php

I am trying to extract the data from several pdf's into a database and I found the code but I can only get it working when inputing a single file each time.

I am using the resource class.pdf2text.php @ http://pastebin.com/hRviHKp1

With the Code:

```
*#this is outside of the loop
   include('class.pdf2text.php'); 

   #this is inside the loop
   $a = new PDF2Text();
   $a->setFilename('$userDoc'); //grab the test file at    
   $a->decodePDF();
   echo $a->output();*
```

The problem I have is after completing the first document successfully, all documents after that return this error Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class PDF2Text in class.pdf2text.php on line 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including the class again somehow, without more code we can't we how. You can instead of using `include` use `include_once` instead and that should fix your error.

Comment: Im including the class at the begining of the code (very first line after <?php) and I have tried include_once with the same results, I will try to grab some more code but theres alot of other junk in there for other file types that could confuse things.

Comment: This error happens if you include a file with the same class twice. Or include another file with a class using the same name defined in it.

Comment: aha you are correct, I combed that code several times seems I should have used search cos I had pasted the include randomely in another function. Thnak you,